# NetBeans 8.0 formatting, ( automatic join string when i push enter ) how to turn it off

Tags: php, netbeans, formatting

Hello i have a problem with NetBeans 8.0. when i push enter, in string NetBeans automatically put me the string to the new line and join the string with ".", but i need it fully in one string.

For example: i want to create:

```
$variable = "Some string
             And next string";
```

But NetBeans 8.0 automatically creates me:

```
$variable = "Some string"
            ."And next string";
```

It not so good for formatting for me. How can i turn it off?

Comment: Ok i found it, it's in: 

Tools -> Options -> Code Completion(tab) and at the bottom of this tab u can see "User String Auto-Concatenation after typed break".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion -> PHP -> Quotes completion: Use String Auto-Concatenation after Typed Break.